# ¿Por qué los input no envían los valores?

Tags: php, wordpress, formularios, post

Estoy trabajando en un formulario para wordpress, en mi plantilla estoy escribiendo el código y:

Los valores de los *Select* si se envían, pero no los de los dos *Input* llamados **el nombre** y **la frase**  Este es el formulario:

```
<form id="el_formulario" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post" >

                <select name="a">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <select name="b">
                    <option value="1">Enero</option>
                    <option value="2">Febrero</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="c" placeholder="AAAA"><br>

                <div class="aire-c"></div>
                <label for="elnombre">Introduce un nombre (opcional)</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name "elnombre"><br><br>
                <label for="lafrase">Introduce una frase (opcional)</label><br>
                    <input name "lafrase" placeholder="Hasta 140 caracteres" rows="<3></3>" maxlength="140"><br>

<!--                Este input guarda el nombre de la acción-->
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="form_luna">

                <input type="submit" class="btn_n" value="Ver el regalo">
            </form>
```

El punto es que en procesar.php sí se reciben los valores de *a*, *b* y *c*, y los puedo procesar, pero no se por qué no llegan **elnombre** y tampoco **lafrase**
El código que procesa es el siguiente:

```
// Primero Verificamos que llegaron todas las variables necesarias
    if( !isset( $_POST['c'] ) || empty( $_POST['c'] ) ):
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'errormsg' => "Por%20favor%20introduce%20un%20año" ), get_home_url()) ); exit;
    endif;
    if ( isset($_POST['elnombre'], $_POST['lafrase']) ):
        $el_nombre = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['elnombre']);
        $la_frase = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['lafrase']);
    elseif ( !isset($_POST['elnombre'], $_POST['lafrase']) ):
        $el_nombre = "No cargó nombre";
        $la_frase = "No cargó frase";
    endif;

    //Sanitizar los valores
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    $c = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['c']);

    // El año primero pasó por sanitización
    $aureo = 0;
    $epacta = 0;
    $ajustab = 0;
    $lafase = 0;
    $imgluna = 0;

    $c = $c+1;
    $aureo = $c % 19;
    $epacta = $aureo - 1;
    $epacta = $epacta * 11;
    $epacta = $epacta % 30;

    if ($b > 2):
        $ajustab = $b - 2;
        $epacta = $epacta + $ajustab;
    endif;

    $a = $a + $epacta;

    if ($a > 29):
        $lafase = $a - 29;
    else:  
        $lafase = $a;
    endif;    

    $allImg = array(
                    "1"=>'img1.png',
                    "2"=>'img1.png',
                    "3"=>'img2.png',
                    "4"=>'img2.png',
                    "25"=>'img8.png',
                    "26"=>'img8.png'
                  );

    $imgfinal = isset($allImg[$lafase]) ? $allImg[$lafase] : 0;

    wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'muestrame' => "Frase:%20" . $la_frase . "%20Nombre:%20" . $el_nombre . "%20Luna:%20" . $imgfinal ), get_home_url() . '/ver-imagen/' ) ); exit;
```

Mucho agradeceré cualquier información, posiblemente sea algún error de principiante tan mínimo que no veo, desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que has escrito mal la etiqueda, has colocado `name "elnombre"` y `name "lafrase"`
y deberia ser:

```
 name ="elnombre"
 name = "lafrase"
```

Comment: Y así de sencillo, se resolvió...
Muchas gracias Igmer Rodríguez